# Steipler keeping 2 days yomtov in Bnei Brak

Tags: eretz-yisrael, yom-tov

I was listening to a shuir of Rav Hershel Schacter and he mentioned that the Steipler kept 2 days yomtov undercover in Bnei Brak. I think he mentioned the source as the Orchos Rabbeinu,even though he did not mention it outright (He mentioned a five volume hanahagos sefer, OR fits the bill). Does anyone know where I can find this?

Comment: I heard the Griz kept two days even in Meah Shearim! I assume you mean because of the Rambam about the messengers?

Comment: I have no doubt the story is in ארוחות רבינו
Zundel Bermans website has it listed for $98 here: https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95---%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%97%D7%96%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A9---%D7%94%22%D7%9B

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is indeed in Orchos Rabbeinu. It can be found in Volume II p. 136 of the 2014 edition. Here is an image of it:

[image: Image of page in Orchos Rabbeinu]